# Mudar o cabeçalho da coluna com formula

Tags: mysql

Eu procurei infinito na internet e não achei, espero que alguém possa me ajudar, eu tenho a seguinte tabela:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

os números -1, -2, -3... representam os meses, ou seja, mês passado(-1), retrasado(-2)... e assim por diante, o que eu preciso é de alguma formula para informar o mês ao invés destes números nessa tabela.
O comando para chegar nesta tabela é o seguinte:

```
SELECT 
(SELECT SUM(quantidade) AS Quantidade
FROM genius.itens_compra
LEFT JOIN genius.compras ON genius.compras.Id = Id_compra
WHERE `Id_produto` = 489 AND EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM `data_compra`) BETWEEN EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM CURDATE() - INTERVAL 10 MONTH) AND EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM CURDATE() - INTERVAL 10 MONTH)
)AS '-10';
```

isso se repete do -10 até o -1, eu só preciso trocar a parte AS '-10' na última linha por algum comando que mê dê uma data

Comment: Vc quer que trocar o -1 por por exemplo Julho?

Comment: Não seria mais sensato fazer na vertical? Coluna Mês e coluna Quantidade? Aí bastaria agrupar por mês e ano, com uma query bem mais curta e reaproveitável.

Comment: sim, seria muito mais simples, mas o que acontece é que eu não posso mudar o banco de dados :/

Comment: exatamente Cleidimar, mas preciso que mude de acordo com o mês atual, por isso preciso de uma formula